# How to make a multiplication of a dask.Dataframe from dask.Series over rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

`normalised = data.mul(alpha, axis=1)`

In the snippet above `data` is a dask.Dataframe and `alpha` is a dask.Series.

Dask raises a `ValueError: Unable to mul dd.Series with axis=1` error while performing this multiplication. This operation works if I compute alpha (e.g alpha.compute() ), but since alpha is a big task I want to avoid calling compute at this stage of the code.

Can anybody come up with a better to solution to perform this operation?

A reproducible example is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3], 
     [1, 2, 3.5], 
     [1, 2, 3.7]], 
    columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

dv = df.iloc[0]
series = dd.from_pandas(dv, npartitions=1)

ddf.mul(series, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation can be performed using `.map_partitions()`. Assuming series.index == ddf.columns then:

```
in_pandas = df.mul(dv, axis=1)
in_dask = ddf.map_partitions(pd.DataFrame.mul, other=series, axis=1, meta=ddf._meta)

import pandas.testing as pdt
pdt.assert_frame_equal(in_pandas, in_dask.compute())
```